# Windows Phone stop image from moving when hold

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-phone-8.1

I am building a Windows Phone 8.1 app with Xamarin and MvvmCross. In this application I show the user a list of images from his pictures library in a Gridview. Some thing that has been bugging me is that when a image in this list is clicked or hold it starts moving, just like a Windows Phone button does. This does happen in other parts of my app too but there it doesn't really matter.

[image]

As you can see the image sometimes falls behind the border of the container or sometimes it creates empty space within the border.

```
 <GridView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Image  Name="item" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PathToThumbnailConverter}}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
 </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

The way I display the images is nothing special. I have tried to search for any attribute that might be needed to stop this from happening but that was without any success.
Can anyone tell me if it is possible to stop the content from moving or if there is another way to at least stop making it visible outside the container.

Comment: for that you have to get GridviewItem style and remove pressed visualstate and assign customized gridviewitem style to your gridview

Comment: @MuhammadSaifullah Yes, After some digging I found out how to properly use the visualstate to remove the pointeruptheme. Thank you very much.